# How to add 30 minutes to my input time and loop it until my input end time in 12HOUR FORMAT (AM/PM)

Tags: java

This is my CODE but this does not stop looping until my end input time it continues to loop, I only want to loop it until my end input time in 12HOUR FORMAT. How can I do this?

```
package javaapplication;

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class JavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String time1 = "09:00"; //my first input time 

        String timeEnds = "4:00"; //my second input time 
        LocalTime timeStart = LocalTime.parse(time1); 

        while(time1!=timeEnds) {
             timeStart = timeStart.plusMinutes(30);           
             System.out.println(""+timeStart);         

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry if you don't understand, But I just want to ask how to add 30 minutes to my first input time and loop it until my input end time in 12HOUR FORMAT. Please take a look at my code upside.

Comment: I mean - use simple and clear sentences with a proper punctuation.

Comment: Thanks for your concern and sorry for my grammar. Anyways I got an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `"4:00"` is not a valid format for local time, as far as `LocalTime.parse(CharSequence)` is concerned. You should use `"04:00"`.

---

A trick to use here is to first check whether the end time is before the start time. If it is, then the end time is in a different halve of the day from the start time. In this case, we add 12 hours to the end time.

When printing the time, we use a custom format `hh:mm`. The small letter `h` means "hour in 12 hour format".

```
String time1 = "09:00"; //my first input time

String timeEnds = "04:00"; //my second input time
LocalTime timeStart = LocalTime.parse(time1);
LocalTime timeEnd = LocalTime.parse(timeEnds);
if (timeStart.isAfter(timeEnd)) {
    timeEnd = timeEnd.plusHours(12);
}

while(timeStart.isBefore(timeEnd)) {
    timeStart = timeStart.plusMinutes(30);
    System.out.println(timeStart.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm")));

}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help I got it. But how can you include AM/PM?

Comment: @JeanetteLucero Use the format `"hh:mm a"`. The character `a` means the AM/PM thingy.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks to your help!